# Imagery Database/Metadata Store

Tags: remote-sensing, database

I'm a Remote Sensing PhD student, and as such I have a large number of satellite images that I'm working with. I'm starting to fail to keep track of them all and I have a lot of metadata that I want to track for each image (sensor, resolution, processing steps, format, source etc).

I have been using the SPECCHIO database for storing Spectral Libraries for a while, and was wondering whether anything similar exists for storing images. I've had a search and can't seem to find anything, but that doesn't mean that it doesn't exist!

Ideally I'm looking for something which can store a database of metadata and allow you to search for images that meet certain criteria (spatial resolution > 10m, or includes a certain lat/long co-ordinate).

Does anyone know if anything like this exists?

If it doesn't exist then I might have a go at writing something, which may involved SQLite, ENVI, IDL and a lot of late nights...

Comment: Yes many Content-based image retrieval (CBIR) systems exist you need to decide which is best for your needs - some are commercial (high-end) TinEye is one
http://www.tineye.com/faq#how Octagon is another
http://octagon.viitala.eu/

Comment: I am remote sensing M.Tech student need satellite images.
Images suitable for pan-sharpening process in matlab i m doing my project
Ineed MS image and Pan image both for the same image.
Ineed database

Comment: This is not an answer. Please consider posting your question as a new question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also look into geo-cataloging tools like [GeoNetowork](http://geonetwork-opensource.org/) (opensource), with the additional benefit of the (normalized) metadata diffusion.